# Change pixels on canvas. It does not work

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Code JavaScript

```
var imgWidth,imgHeight,datosPrint;
    window.onload = function(){
        /*canvas,ctx,img...*/
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
        var datosDeLaImagen = ctx.getImageData(0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
        datosPrint = datosDeLaImagen.data;
        invertirColores(canvas,ctx);
    };
```

ctx.getImageData is not work. Why?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors, simply it not advance. 
I think it's all right

Comment: Are you using `img.onload`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 'img.onload'. Using NetBeans, It works and runs 'ctx.getImageData()'. But when I execute that code in Chrome normally (executing file html), It does not work. I do not understand why that happens...

Comment: Do you also have an onerror handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont just manipulate the data object and see the changes, you have to put the manipulations back into the context when your done.

```
var imgWidth,imgHeight,datosPrint;
    window.onload = function(){
        /*canvas,ctx,img...*/
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
        var datosDeLaImagen = ctx.getImageData(0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
        datosPrint = datosDeLaImagen.data;
        invertirColores(canvas,ctx);
        ctx.putImageData(datosPrint, 0, 0)
    };
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData